# change primary key on insert if duplicate

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm importing my trades from my brokerage house.  My trades have an identifier called a transactionid.  I have made transactionid my primary key in my local database.  ACH deposits have a transactionid of “0”.  I wanted to import transactions, and make the primary key for deposits a concatenation of account number, date, and time.  I started by making a trigger that doesn’t seem to work.  I keep getting an error of “Unknown column 'transactionid' in 'field list'” when I import data into the table.

When I drop the trigger, I can import fine as long as I don’t have deposits in the import.  I have also changed my concatenation to a static number to help test, but my trigger still causes the above error to be thrown.

Here is the trigger I built:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `investments`.`concatPrimaryKeyIf0` BEFORE INSERT ON investments.transactions FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (transactionid = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO transactions
   #SET transactionid = concat(account_number,"_",`date`,"_",`time`);
   SET transactions.transactionid = 5;
   END IF;
END;
```

How can I update the primary key on the import?

Comment: Changing the primary key is a super bad idea as it's often involved in relationships with other tables. Why are you intending to do this? Compute the key when importing, then deal with duplicates as they emerge. MySQL suffers badly from overly long primary keys as well, a secondary column with a `UNIQUE` constraint usually performs better.

Comment: You don't INSERT INTO a table from it's own trigger, you're not actually allowed to at all; pretty sure you can get away with just the commented out SET you have with a minor modification `SET NEW.transactionid = `... but I agree with tadman's comment, it is best not to mess with PKs like this; if the field value is not unique, it should not be used as a PK.

Comment: @tadman I agree that changing primary keys is usually bad.  But, in this case my extracts from a foreign source have a key of 0 on some transactions.  The entire schema is relating to this table only after import.  I need to make sure that I don't lose data due to duplicates if they are "0".  At the same time, If importing and data already exists, I need it to upsert.  What do you mean by a secondary column with a UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: MySQL's primary key is used as the key in indexes, so having a very heavy-weight primary bloats index sizes considerably. This is because unlike Postgres, MySQL has no private internal row-identifier number, it just uses the primary key. Having a standard `INT` or `BIGINT` `PRIMARY KEY` column means the indexes only have to deal with 4 or 8 bytes of data, max, and it keeps them compact. Create a regular `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` column, plus a secondary `transaction_id VARCHAR(255)` and add a `UNIQUE` constraint. It will work just the same without the performance hit.

Comment: Plus then you can cross-link records to this table using your internal identifier number instead of some big, ugly string. That usually makes lookups a lot faster as well and you can set nice foreign-key relationships if you want.

Comment: @tadman Never mind.  I was blanking out.  I hardly ever use the UNIQUE constraint, and forgot about that.  I know what it is and you don't have to explain. But, I don't have a good way to computing the key as it comes in, that is why I was trying to create a trigger on insert.

Comment: Thanks.  Good idea to just have auto increment and then can I combo the unique constraint since the transactionid will still be duplicated when "0"?

Comment: You need to have some kind of procedurally generated key that is stable for any given row of data and then you can use that for an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` test. I'm not sure how you'd generate the keys otherwise. If you're populating with `0` and not `NULL`, which bypasses duplicate constraints, you should be good.